# I'm having trouble with fixing the spacing in my header for my website (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: bootstrap-4, spacing

I'm currently working on a website for my restaurant but I ran into a problem that keeps annoying me. I created a navbar but there is lots of unwanted space on the left side of the navitems and right side. I don't know if it's just because of my monitor or if its a spacing issue on my end. I have linked the code below. Please help!

```
    <!-- Navigation -->

<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #354147 !important;">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
            <h1>Pho & Grill</h1>
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link active">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="menu.html" class="nav-link">Menu</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="location.html" class="nav-link">Location</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

<!-- End Navigation -->
```

and the css:

```
.navbar-brand h1 {
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: 'Felipa', sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #FBD784; 
  }

.navbar {
   font-size: 1.15rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   letter-spacing: .1rem;
   box-shadow: 0 .5rem .5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   z-index: 1; 
 }

.nav-item {
   padding: .5rem;
 }

.nav-link {
   color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-link.active, .nav-link:hover {
   color: #FBD784 !important;
}
```